# Custom Shared Preferences Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preference, listpreference

I have set the Preferences in xml and I have the folowing Activity:

```
public class Preferencias extends PreferenceActivity {

//SharedPreferences prefs;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    setContentView(R.layout.preferences);

    Button bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.selectPic);
    TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String def=getResources().getString(R.string.noDefinido);
    tv.setText(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("logo", def));


    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                intent.setClassName(getApplicationContext(),
                        SDCardImagesActivity.class.getName());
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    //habra que sacarlo de la red
    String [] ofis ={"Venus", "Europa"};
    ListPreference lp=new ListPreference(this);
    lp.setValue("oficina");
    lp.setEntries(ofis);
    lp.setEntryValues(ofis);
    lp.setTitle(R.string.oficina);
    lp.setDefaultValue(ofis[1]);


    getPreferenceScreen().addPreference(lp);


}
}
```

It works fine with the xml preferences but I also need to add a preference in code the reason of it is that the options of this ListPreference will come from the database (here I have the String array for now). The problem is the data changed for this preference is not persisted. When I make the changes I press back button I come back the value goes back to default value. How could I make sure this preference is saved too?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved I included the preference without setting up its data then in code:

```
String [] ofis ={"Venus", "Europa"}; 
ListPreference lp=(ListPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("oficina");  
lp.setEntries(ofis); 
lp.setEntryValues(ofis); 
lp.setDefaultValue(ofis[1]);
```

works fine now